# Deployment of database with Winform application

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, deployment

I need a help in deploying the Winform app. I have a db (sql) file in which login details are kept. I need to deploy with my application so that user can login and change password.

I don't have any idea how to do this.

please help

Comment: Have you checked this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574846/how-to-deploy-a-windows-forms-database-application

Comment: You may find this post helpful: [How to deploy application with sql server database on clients](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956142/how-to-deploy-application-with-sql-server-database-on-clients)